# Как подключить правильно шрифт ROBOTO

Tags: android-sdk, android

Доброго времени суток. Дело в том, что Roboto это очень красивый шрифт, но он появляется только по-моему в 3.0 или даже 4.0. а я хочу чтоб этот шрифт был на всех девайсах. Я его скачал в assets, но подключаю его как-то по глупому и у меня есть такое чувство что как-то это можно сделать проще. вот пример как я им пользуюсь:

```
loginText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginText);
        Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
        loginText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        poputkaText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.poputkaText);
        myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
        poputkaText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        passText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passText);
        myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
        passText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        welcomeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcomeText);
        myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
        welcomeText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        errorText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);
        myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
        errorText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        okBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
        okBtn.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        cancelBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
        cancelBtn.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        regBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
        myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
        regBtn.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        forgetBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkForgetPassword);
        myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
                "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");
        forgetBtn.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

то есть приходится подключать даже те вьюхи которым в принципе можно и не присваивать айдишник.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте собственный контрол (потомок `TextView`), который будет юзать необходимый шрифт.  И используйте вметсо `TextView` в `xml`.

Готовое решение на [GitHab](https://github.com/neopixl/PixlUI)

Answer (score 1):

Наследуй TextView, в конструкторе можешь выставить шрифт. Далее используешь этот кастомный TextView там где нужен шрифт, там где не нужен - стандартный.

Тоже самое можно с Button сделать